# Convert object to integer in PHP

Tags: php, types

- The value of $total_results = 10
- $total_results in an object, according to gettype()
- I cannot use mathematical operators on $total_results because it's not numeric
- Tried $total_results = intval($total_results) to convert to an integer, but no luck
- The notice I get is: Object of class Zend_Gdata_Extension_OpenSearchTotalResults could not be converted to int

How can I convert to an integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$val = intval($total_results->getText());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$results_numeric = (int) $total_results;
```

or maybe this:

```
$results_numeric = $total_results->count();
```

Comment: (int) does the same as calling intval().

Comment: But int is 300 to 600% faster

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the object has a build in method to get it as an integer?

Otherwise try this very hacky approach (relys on __toString() returning that 10)

```
$total_results = $total_results->__toString();
$total_results = intval($total_results);
```

However if the object has a build in non-magic method, you should use that!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the methods of the class [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Gdata/Gdata/Zend_Gdata_Extension_OpenSearchTotalResults.html). Then you can try out the different methods yourself. There is a getText() method for example.

Comment: I'm new to OO, thanks for pointing out/reminding about methods of the class.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
class toValue {
    function __toString()
    {
        return '3'; // you must return a string
    }
}

$a = new toValue;

var_dump("$a" + 2);
```

result:
int(5)