# Convert object to integer

Tags: php, zend-framework, types, casting

### Convert object to integer in PHP

I want to round figure the value of `$row->getValue();` . I used following two functions for that - -

1. round(x,prec);
2. intval(x);

But both function give error

> Object of class Zend_Gdata_Analytics_Extension_Metric could not be
>   converted to int

Now what is the way to overcome from this ??
Thank you . . .

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($row->getValue());`?

Comment: Do a `Zend_Debug::dump($row->getValue());` and paste the output?

Comment: what is the value you're getting in $row->getValue()? If it IS an integer then store it in a variable and then round it off. Like $val = $row->getValue(): then round($val);

Comment: Use `intval($row->getText());` it should solve problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$str = (string)$row->getValue();

// Int representation
$str_int = intval($str);

// Float, if needed
$str_float = floatval($str);

// Use them where you want..
```

Comment: Direct way: `$int = (int) (string) $row->getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

What type of $row?

For a start try:

```
intval($row->getValue()->getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this now :

```
$val = intval($row->getText());
```

Or:

```
$val = intval($row->getValue()->getText());
```

Comment: `@Bogdan Burim` Yes...and your previous answer is also working ...please post it again...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$intVal = intval($product->getValue());
```

This question is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583157/convert-object-to-integer-in-php)